# Referencing local nuget packages from .fsx file

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have a local nuget repository on my computer since i'm away from the internet for long periods of time, but would like to be able to run my projects without going to a wifi hub.

Answer (score 1):

[This might help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tools/fsharp-interactive/#referencing-packages-in-f-interactive), even though it's not exactly what you want:

> You can also specify a package source with the #i command. The following example specifies a remote and a local source:

```
#i "nuget:https://my-remote-package-source/index.json"
#i @"path-to-my-local-source"
```

> This will tell the resolution engine under the covers to also take into account the remote and/or local sources added to a script.